# Android custom lint for duplicate strings

Tags: android, lint

**Problem**

I am writing a custom lint rule (using this [example](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-custom-lint-rules)) for finding dupe strings that are declared using unique string variable. For eg, in `strings.xml`,

```
<string name="cancel">Cancel</string> 
<string name="activity_cancel_text">Cancel</string>
```

**Expectation**
Show `lint` warning when `activity_cancel_text` is added to strings.xml

**Approach**
- When `strings.xml` is opened by the developer for the first time, read through entire file and maintain a hashmap as 
`key` = `"Cancel"` and `value` = `"cancel"`
- Visit each element ie the string value (`Cancel` on line #2 in this case) and if the key exists in map, raise a lint issue warning)

**Question** Need to read the strings.xml before `visitElement()` is called. How to do that?

Documentation is sparse and debugging is hard even with unit test (breakpoint never gets hit). So whatever progress I've made is through trial and error after reading tens of blogs. To test my changes, I install the custom lint jar to `~/.android/lint` and make changes to a test Android project to observe lint warnings.

**StringDupeDetector.java**

```
package com.example.lint.checks;

import com.android.SdkConstants;
import com.android.resources.ResourceFolderType;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Category;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Context;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Implementation;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Issue;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Location;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.ResourceXmlDetector;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Scope;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.Severity;
import com.android.tools.lint.detector.api.XmlContext;

import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class StringDupeDetector extends ResourceXmlDetector  {

    public StringDupeDetector() {}

    public static final Issue ISSUE = Issue.create(
            // ID: used in @SuppressLint warnings etc
            "StringDupe",

            // Title -- shown in the IDE's preference dialog, as category headers in the
            // Analysis results window, etc
            "String Dupe",

            // Full explanation of the issue; you can use some markdown markup such as
            // `monospace`, *italic*, and **bold**.
            "This check highlights string/color/dimen literals in code which duplicates " +
                    "the string resources. Blah blah blah.\n" +
                    "\n" +
                    "Another paragraph here.\n",
            Category.CORRECTNESS,
            6,
            Severity.ERROR,
            new Implementation(
                    StringDupeDetector.class,
                    Scope.RESOURCE_FILE_SCOPE));

    private static final Map<String, String> stringResourceMap = new HashMap<>(); // string, stringId
    private static final Map<String, Location> violationsMap = new HashMap(); // string, location
    private static final String ISSUE_MSG_FORMAT = "WARNING! %s is already defined as %s.";

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Collection<String> getApplicableElements() {
        return Collections.singletonList(SdkConstants.TAG_STRING);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean appliesTo(ResourceFolderType folderType) {
        return folderType == ResourceFolderType.VALUES;
    }


    @Override
    public void visitElement(@NotNull XmlContext context, @NotNull Element element) {
        final String string = element.getTextContent();
        final String stringId = element.getAttribute(SdkConstants.ATTR_NAME);

        if (stringResourceMap.containsKey(string)) {
            // found a dupe!
            violationsMap.put(string, context.getLocation(element));
            context.report(ISSUE, element, context.getLocation(element), String.format(ISSUE_MSG_FORMAT, string, stringId));
        } else {
            stringResourceMap.put(string, stringId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find the solution?